# How to make the target view a subview of window using storyboard segue?

Tags: ios, storyboard, fullscreen

I am using storyboard and trying to segue from a bar view to a full screen view where the bar view's parent view is the same size as the bar view and is clipping subviews, but I'd like the destination view to take the full screen. Is there an easy way to do this by setting the properties of either the segue or the destination view controller? What is the proper way to do this? I really would like to make the full screen view a subview of window.

Thanks for any suggestions!

- Luverio

Comment: more info: I tried to set the destination view controller's attribute size to "Full iPhone/iPad screen size" but the view is still clipped.

Comment: What do you mean by a "bar view"?

Comment: Sorry, by bar view I mean a view with a single toolbar inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go around the segue by manually instantiate the target view controller and add it as the window's `rootViewController`.